# How to read a property `ms-Mcs-AdmPwdExpirationTime` from ActiveDirectory

Tags: vb.net, active-directory

I am trying to read **Expiration time of administrator password** from `ActiveDirectory`:

```
Dim DC = New  PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain)
Dim cmp = ComputerPrincipal.FindByIdentity(DC, hostnm)
Dim desting As String = cmp.DistinguishedName
Dim de As New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" & desting)
pwdexp = de.Properties("ms-Mcs-AdmPwdExpirationTime").Value.ToString()
```

But what I see is just `<COM Type>`:
[image]

However, *expiration time of administrator password* can be easily read by **PowerShell**:

```
$TestValue = [adsi]"LDAP://CN=xxx,OU=xxx,OU=xxx,OU=xxx,OU=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xx"
$TestValue.ConvertLargeIntegerToInt64($Testvalue."ms-Mcs-AdmPwdExpirationTime"[0])
```

And I know that there is a such property:
[image]

Interestingly, but I can read another parameter `ms-Mcs-AdmPwd`:

```
Dim DC = New  PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain)
Dim cmp = ComputerPrincipal.FindByIdentity(DC, hostnm)
Dim desting As String = cmp.DistinguishedName
Dim de As New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" & desting)
pwdexp = de.Properties("ms-Mcs-AdmPwdExpirationTime").Value.ToString()
```

and value can be seen from debugger:

[image]

How to read a property `ms-Mcs-AdmPwdExpirationTime` correctly?

Comment: This is not VBA. Please correct the tag to VB.NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value is DateTime which is represented as LargeInteger in the AD. You must convert it to being able to read it.

Notice that in PowerShell you are converting the value using `ConvertLargeIntegerToInt64`. So, we need to do same first too.

The code in C#

```
            /// <summary>
            /// Decodes IADsLargeInteger objects into a FileTime format (long)
            /// </summary>
            public static long ConvertLargeIntegerToLong(object largeInteger)
            {
                var type = largeInteger.GetType();
                var highPart = (int)type.InvokeMember("HighPart", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, largeInteger, null);
                var lowPart = (int)type.InvokeMember("LowPart", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, largeInteger, null);

                return (long)highPart << 32 | (uint)lowPart;
            }
```

and in VB.NET (using http://converter.telerik.com/)

```
''' <summary>
''' Decodes IADsLargeInteger objects into a FileTime format (long)
''' </summary>
Public Shared Function ConvertLargeIntegerToLong(largeInteger As Object) As Long
    Dim type = largeInteger.[GetType]()
    Dim highPart = CInt(type.InvokeMember("HighPart", BindingFlags.GetProperty, Nothing, largeInteger, Nothing))
    Dim lowPart = CInt(type.InvokeMember("LowPart", BindingFlags.GetProperty, Nothing, largeInteger, Nothing))

    Return CLng(highPart) << 32 Or CUInt(lowPart)
End Function
```

and then read the date value using below

```
var pwdExpTime = DateTime.FromFileTime(ConvertLargeIntegerToLong(de.Properties["ms-Mcs-AdmPwdExpirationTime"].Value));
```

and in VB.NET by

```
Dim pwdExpTime = DateTime.FromFileTime(ConvertLargeIntegerToLong(de.Properties("ms-Mcs-AdmPwdExpirationTime").Value))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It is majestic! :)

Answer (score 0):

I get an error using the accepted answer and `ms-Mcs-AdmPwdExpirationTime` set to 133004656837955708 (should result in 23.06.2022 15:48:03).

With this date the lowPart is negative and cannot be cast with CUInt.

So I mixed two solutions I found:

```
Public Shared Function ConvertLargeIntegerToLong(largeInteger As Object) As Long
    Dim type = largeInteger.[GetType]()
    Dim highPart = CInt(type.InvokeMember("HighPart", BindingFlags.GetProperty, Nothing, largeInteger, Nothing))
    Dim lowPart = CInt(type.InvokeMember("LowPart", BindingFlags.GetProperty, Nothing, largeInteger, Nothing))
    If lowPart < 0 Then
        Dim tempStr as String = "&H" + CStr(Hex(highPart)) + CStr(Hex(lowPart))
        Return Val(tempStr)
    Else
        Return CLng(highPart) << 32 Or CUInt(lowPart)
    End If
End Function
```